# Cannot establish VPN connection in Azure

Tags: vpn, azure, connection

Today started to get this message:
The connection was prevented because of a policy configured on your RAS/VPN server. Specifically, the authentication method used by the server to verify your username and password may not match the authentication method configured in your connection profile. Please contact the Administrator of the RAS server and notify them of this error. (Error 812)

What could be the reason? Nothing was changed on our end.

Comment: if you think nothing was changed - doesnt mean nothing was changed...

Comment: I see. Last time I was successfully using Azure VPN on Friday. I understand, that something has changed on Azure side, but what and how to mitigate? The error is reported after specifying VPN certificate during running VPN client.

Comment: @Sergei which VPN type do you have? P2S connection, or S2S connection?  Please refer to this [doc](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vpn-gateway/vpn-gateway-about-vpngateways).

Comment: Nancy, this is about P2S connection. I start "Connect", it asks my certificate, and fails with error above. Nobody changed VPNs configuration. We have 3 VPNs, all are failing now.

Answer (score 3):

I found the reason.
Microsoft stopped supporting TLS1.0 and TLS1.1
As my client computer is Windows7, I receive this error.
Mitigation is described here: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vpn-gateway/vpn-gateway-vpn-faq#tls1

Thanks to all for participation,
Sergei.

Answer (score 0):

From your description and comment i assume its a Point-To-Site connection.

If that is the case then the issue is with certificate used for VPN connection, either on the VPN Gateway or on your laptop.

To make is simple the certificate has either expire or they don't match.

Review the process:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vpn-gateway/vpn-gateway-howto-point-to-site-resource-manager-portal

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hannel, thank you for your post. I checked all, and all is good: certificate is active until 2031, root certificate didn't change and is  the same as before. We have 3 VPNs and all started to fail connecting with above error. I still don't know the reason and what can I do on my side. So far it looks that something has changed on Azure side.